# lightslider how to get rid of the dots

Tags: javascript, html

I have uploaded 445 (!) pictures of my wedding to a website and trying to use a slider. So far, I found "lightslider.js" which gives me some nice results. The only problem I'm now facing is that I have as many dots as the number of pictures I'm referring to (as the picture below shows).

Is there a means to get rid of these dots and maybe to replace them by something "smarter"? I'm open to any suggestion.

I hope my question will be useful to someone else in this community.

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightslider.min.css" />
            <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
    <meta name="description" content="Mariage de .. et .. " />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    
    <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    
    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery" style="max-width: 500px;">
            <ul id="lightSlider">
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-001-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-001-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-002-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-002-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-003-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-003-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-004-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-004-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-005-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-005-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-006-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-006-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-007-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-007-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-008-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-008-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-009-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-009-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-010-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-010-web.png"/></a></li>
                <!-- And so on until ... -->
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-440-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-440-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-441-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-441-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-442-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-442-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-443-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-443-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-444-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-444-web.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="img/wedding-445-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="img/wedding-445-web.png"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            <img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto !important;" id="picture" src="img/wedding-001-web.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({autoWidth:true, enableDrag:false});
                $("#lightSlider img").click( function() {
                        $('#picture').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
                        $('#picture').attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

lightslider.min.css:

```
/*! lightslider - v1.1.3 - 2015-04-14
* https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider
.lSSlideWrapper .lSSlide,.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade>*{-webkit-transition-timing-function:inherit!important;transition-timing-function:inherit!important;-webkit-transition-duration:inherit!important;transition-duration:inherit!important}
.lSSlideOuter,.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery{-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:after,.lSSlideWrapper>.lightSlider:after{clear:both}
.lSSlideOuter{overflow:hidden;user-select:none}
.lightSlider:after,.lightSlider:before{content:" ";display:table}
.lightSlider{overflow:hidden;margin:0}
.lSSlideWrapper{max-width:100%;overflow:hidden}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSSlide{-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);-ms-transform:translate(0,0);transform:translate(0,0);-webkit-transition:all 1s;-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform,height;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform,height;transition-property:transform,height}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade>*{position:absolute!important;top:0;left:0;z-index:9;margin-right:0;width:100%}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade>*{opacity:0;-webkit-transition-delay:0s;transition-delay:0s;-webkit-transition-property:opacity;transition-property:opacity}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade>.active{z-index:10}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade>.active{opacity:1}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg{margin:10px 0 0;padding:0;text-align:center}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg>li{cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;padding:0 5px}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg>li a{background-color:#222;border-radius:30px;display:inline-block;height:8px;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-999em;width:8px;position:relative;z-index:99;-webkit-transition:all .5s linear 0s;transition:all .5s linear 0s}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg>li.active a,.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg>li:hover a{background-color:#428bca}
.lSSlideOuter .media{opacity:.8}
.lSSlideOuter .media.active{opacity:1}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery{list-style:none;padding-left:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;user-select:none}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li{overflow:hidden;-webkit-transition:border-radius .12s linear 0s .35s linear 0s;transition:border-radius .12s linear 0s .35s linear 0s}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li.active,.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li:hover{border-radius:5px}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery img{display:block;height:auto;max-width:100%}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:after,.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:before{content:" ";display:table}
.lSAction>a{width:32px;display:block;top:50%;height:32px;background-image:url(../img/controls.png);cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:99;margin-top:-16px;opacity:.5;-webkit-transition:opacity .35s linear 0s;transition:opacity .35s linear 0s}
.lSAction>a:hover{opacity:1}
.lSAction>.lSPrev{background-position:0 0;left:10px}
.lSAction>.lSNext{background-position:-32px 0;right:10px}
.lSAction>a.disabled{pointer-events:none}
.cS-hidden{height:1px;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);overflow:hidden}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical{position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical.noPager{padding-right:0!important}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .lSGallery{position:absolute!important;right:0;top:0}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .lightSlider>*{width:100%!important;max-width:none!important}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .lSAction>a{left:50%;margin-left:-14px;margin-top:0}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .lSAction>.lSNext{background-position:31px -31px;bottom:10px;top:auto}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .lSAction>.lSPrev{background-position:0 -31px;bottom:auto;top:10px}
.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl{direction:rtl}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager,.lSSlideOuter .lightSlider{padding-left:0;list-style:none}
.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .lSPager,.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .lightSlider{padding-right:0}
.lSSlideOuter .lSGallery li,.lSSlideOuter .lightSlider>*{float:left}
.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .lSGallery li,.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .lightSlider>*{float:right!important}
@-webkit-keyframes rightEnd{0%,100%{left:0}
50%{left:-15px}
}
@keyframes rightEnd{0%,100%{left:0}
50%{left:-15px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes topEnd{0%,100%{top:0}
50%{top:-15px}
}
@keyframes topEnd{0%,100%{top:0}
50%{top:-15px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftEnd{0%,100%{left:0}
50%{left:15px}
}
@keyframes leftEnd{0%,100%{left:0}
50%{left:15px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes bottomEnd{0%,100%{bottom:0}
50%{bottom:-15px}
}
@keyframes bottomEnd{0%,100%{bottom:0}
50%{bottom:-15px}
}
.lSSlideOuter .rightEnd{-webkit-animation:rightEnd .3s;animation:rightEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter .leftEnd{-webkit-animation:leftEnd .3s;animation:leftEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .rightEnd{-webkit-animation:topEnd .3s;animation:topEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter.vertical .leftEnd{-webkit-animation:bottomEnd .3s;animation:bottomEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .rightEnd{-webkit-animation:leftEnd .3s;animation:leftEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lSSlideOuter.lSrtl .leftEnd{-webkit-animation:rightEnd .3s;animation:rightEnd .3s;position:relative}
.lightSlider.lsGrab>*{cursor:-webkit-grab;cursor:-moz-grab;cursor:-o-grab;cursor:-ms-grab;cursor:grab}
.lightSlider.lsGrabbing>*{cursor:move;cursor:-webkit-grabbing;cursor:-moz-grabbing;cursor:-o-grabbing;cursor:-ms-grabbing;cursor:grabbing}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html
You can set `pager:false` to disable the dots.

So you will just update your existing `lightSlider` call to the following:

```
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({autoWidth:true, enableDrag:false,pager:false});
```

Comment: thank you, do I need to put this in my html file? in the head or body section ?

Comment: I see at the end of your `body` tag, you already have the code above, so you simply just add one more parameter to your `$("#lightSlider").lightSlider(..., pager: false)` and you are all set

Comment: @Laurent, I updated my answer but you just need to change your EXISTING call to `lightslider`.